# make a bundle offer from simple products

Tags: bundled-product, offers

actually i have a problem similar to the above request; I want to make a bundle product or grouped from 1 quantity each of two simple products; and like that, the client will add to cart 1 bundle or maybe more. how can i do this? thanks in advance for help and support!!

Comment: no one can help ?